# What's the best way to say "whatever" as in fine?

Tags: traducción

I've heard so many ways Spanish people say **whatever** for sentences like:

> -**Whatever**, do what you want
> -Ok, I'll do it, **whatever!**

What's the best translation of this in Spanish?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Note that the answer may depend on the country, so you could help us by providing a specific country or region you would like the answers to be more oriented to. On the other hand, the answers may also depend on the specific sentence. Maybe there's a better word for your first example and another for the second one. That happens sometimes. So you could help us by explaining what are the true intentions of the speaker behind those "whatevers".

Comment: "I've heard so many ways Spanish people say whatever for sentences like:" Please tell us  what they are.....

Answer (score 3):

There are regional (idiomatic) variations you may hear for the equivalent Spanish sentences.

These examples may be representative but not exhaustive to all ways in different countries (but will be well understood regardless their flavor though)

> **Whatever**, do what you want
>
> - **Listo, no [me] importa** [hacé/haz] lo que quieras (ie Arg. or Uruguay)
> - **Vale**, haz lo que quieras (España)
> - "Como quieras **[Me] da lo mismo [/igual]**

> Ok, i'll do it. **Whatever**
>
> - Bueno, lo haré. **Sea lo que sea**
> - Bueno, [lo [haré/voy a hacerlo]. **Como sea**
> - Bien, lo hago. **No** [me] **importa nada** (I don't care much for the consecuences)

Comment: Yes, - [1] *Vale, haz lo que quieras* and [2] - “Vale, lo haré” are perfectly idiomatic in Spain.

Answer (score 2):

"Whatever" in English is used in a number of different contexts, and may not neatly map onto a single word 1-1 for all these meanings. For example, those in your example sentences would seem to be captured by:

> ### [whatever](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/whatever)
>
> ...
> <sub>INTERJECTION</sub>
> 4. (used to express indifference)
>
> 1. **lo que sea**
>    ShalI I order coffee or tea? - Whatever. — *¿Pido café o té? - Lo que sea.*
> 2. **me da igual**
>    Do you want to come with me? - Whatever. — *¿Quieres acompañarme? - Me da igual.*
> 3. **como sea**
>    Do you want to go to the beach or to a museum? - Whatever. — *¿Quieres ir a la playa o a un museo? - Como sea.*

> 5. (used to express irritation)
>
>    1. **me da igual**
>       I'll confiscate your phone if you don't do your chores. - Whatever! — *Te sacaré el teléfono si no haces los quehaceres. - ¡Me da igual!*

Answer (score 1):

It really does depend on the tone of the conversation and the context. Assuming that they are having a sort of argument, these are the most idiomatic (Spanish from Spain) translations I can think of:

**—Whatever, do what you want**

- Mira, haz lo que te dé la gana.
- Es que me da igual/lo mismo, haz lo que quieras.

**—Ok, I'll do it, whatever!**

- Pues eso voy a hacer, ¡lo que me dé la gana!
- Vale, eso haré. ¡Gracias por nada/por tu ayuda! (sarcastic)

As I said, these are translations that only fit if the tone of the conversation is hostile. More information on the context is needed to propose a precise translation.

Answer (score 0):

As used in the sentences provided:

> -**Whatever**, do what you want
>
> -Ok, I'll do it, **whatever**!

"whatever" can be translated as:

- lo que sea
- sea lo que sea
- sea lo que fuera
- no importa lo que sea
- cualquier cosa

At the beginning of a sentence, and set off by commas, I'd use "no importa lo que sea":

- **No importa lo que sea,** haz lo que quieras. (In countries where "vos" is used for second person singular: No importa lo que sea, hacé lo que quieras.)

At the end of the sentence, also set off by commas, I'd use "sea lo que sea/fuera" or "no importa lo que sea":

- De acuerdo, lo haré, **sea lo que sea / no importa lo que sea.**

The forms "lo que sea" and "cualquier cosa" will tend to be used as subjects or objects (i.e. not set off by commas) and with the subjunctive of *ser* or any other verb:

- Whatever you do will be fine: **lo que sea que hagas** va a estar bien, **lo que hagas** / **cualquier cosa que hagas** va a estar bien (the first one is more emphatic, being similar to "whatever it is that you do...")
- I'll do whatever you want: haré **lo que quieras**.
- I'll do whatever you say: haré **cualquier cosa que digas**.